# Как вызвать функцию после полной загрузки объекта?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, promise

Функция возвращает объект. Проблема в том, что объект не успевает полностью загрузиться, а функция уже отрабатывает.
Вот код:

```
function createYaMetrika()
{
    return new Ya.Metrika({
        id:9999999,
        webvisor:true,
        clickmap:true,
        trackLinks:true,
        accurateTrackBounce:true,
        ut:"noindex"
    });
}
```

Лог показывает, что ut не успевает загрузиться, из-за этого приходит ошибка 
`ReferenceError: Ya is not defined`
Вызов:

```
function sendYaMetrika(goal) {
    if (typeof window.yaCounter9999999 == 'undefined') {
        window.yaCounter9999999 = createYaMetrika();
    }

    window.yaCounter9999999.reachGoal(goal);
}
```

Хотелось бы решить проблему с использованием `promise`, но с ним мало опыта работы(

Comment: откуда ты берешь объект Ya?

Comment: Прежде чем назначать конкурс, стоило привести в порядок вопрос и добавить всю необходимую информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может использовать код из документации:

> Определить, готов ли счетчик к работе, можно с помощью специального
>   JavaScript события. При этом необходимо добавить параметр triggerEvent
>   со значением true в код счетчика. Для jQuery можно использовать
>   следующий пример кода до момента инициализации счетчика:

```
jQuery(document).on('yacounterXXXXXinited', function () {
    console.log('счетчик yaCounterXXXXX можно использовать');
});
```

p/s :
Общая концепция такова, ты инициализируеш счетчик , добавляя триггер `triggerEvent` к параметрам счетчика , далее слушаеш событие, как только счетчик будет готов он вызовет событие. В общем виде код должен выглядеть примерно так :

```
    var yandexId = 23275000 ;
    (function (d, w, c) {
    (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() {
        try {
            w.yandexMetrika = new Ya.Metrika({
                id:yandexId,
                clickmap:true,
                trackLinks:true,
                accurateTrackBounce:true,
                webvisor:true,
                ecommerce:"dataLayer",
                triggerEvent:1
            });
        } catch(e) { }
    });

    var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
        s = d.createElement("script"),
        f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); };
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";

    if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
        d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
    } else { f(); }
})(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");

$(document).on('yacounter' + yandexId + 'inited', function () {
    console.log(window.yandexMetrika);
});
```

Comment: событие не отрабатывает

Comment: Покажи событие и код счетчика

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/443th0ak/

Comment: Ты пытаешся слушать событие до его инициализации, оно никогда не выполнится. Добавил в ответ пример.

Comment: Спасибо) Все работает